# Table row content bleeding into sticky header content when scrolling - relative vs absolute positioning related

Tags: html, css, html-table, ellipsis

I am working on a table where I need to add ellipsis to text displayed in table rows if they exceed two lines.

Using a solution from [here](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/)

I have now incorporated this into table cells, and have the ellipsis behaviour working.

However I also have a sticky table header to keep it in view whilst scrolling the table rows, but I am finding the table rows that have the special ellipsis behaviour class applied are bleeding through into the header content when scrolling:

[image]

Working demo here -> https://codepen.io/parky128-the-vuer/pen/vYYBQmJ

I have tracked this down to the usage of `position: relative;` in the `multiLineEllipsis` mixin since I can comment this out and the behaviour doesnt happen, but then I lose the placement of the '...' content which is being absolute positioned.

Is there a way I can preserve the behaviour of the mixin along with a sticky table header?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `th`'s `z-index` value to a higher value than the actual data should solve the problem. Demo: https://codepen.io/zeus2198/pen/xxxKmLY